# jQueryUI Dialog doesn't apply button classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm using jQueryUI to build some modal boxes. I've created and implemented a default theme. My problem is that there are no classes applied to the buttons which I create through the dialog prefences

```
var userSettingsDialog = jQuery('#userSettingsDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { "Save": function() { jQuery(this).dialog('close'); },
                    "Cancel": function() { jQuery(this).dialog('close'); }
                },
        modal: true
    });
```

It creates the two buttons but they don't have any class supplied

```
<button type="button">Save</button>
<button type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if this is a bit obvious but are buttons included in your jQuery UI download? I only mention it because in the past I've downloaded a custom version of jQuery UI excluding functionality I didn't think I would need, but then subsequently have used and been confused as to why it didn't work.